# Titanium Infinite Scroll : Not working

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am trying to add views to my scroll view when it reaches 40% scroll. This is the way I am doing it :

```
scrollView.add(//add first 10 initial containerView's);
var triggerScroll = true; 
var scrollPercentage = 0; 
scrollView.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { 
var devHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight; 
    var currPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if(currPos > devHeight){
        currPos = currPos - devHeight;
    }

    scrollPercentage = (currPos)/devHeight * 100;

    if(scrollPercentage > 40 && triggerScroll){
        triggerScroll = false;
        var containerView = myapp.createMyView();
        scrollView.add(containerView);
    }

    //reset scroll to true after the offset reaches end of the screen, so that the 
    //'scroll' event listener only gets called ONCE every time it crosses 40%
    if(scrollPercentage > 101){
        triggerScroll = true;
    }

});
```

But its just not working. I am trying to support infinite scroll in my vertical scroll view. Any idea whats going wrong ?

Comment: does myapp.createMyView() return a view with set properties? Or just an empty view object?

Comment: a view with set properties..

Comment: from the looks of it, this code will only add one view. After one view is added. triggerScroll is set to false, which will fail the if statement

Comment: but the moment the scroll offset crosses the devHeight the scrollPercentage is set to a number more than 100. This will reset the triggerScroll boolean

Comment: hmm.. I will try to re create the issue

Comment: Sure Alexander.. Thanks dude :)

Comment: Seeing a funny behavior. The device heigth, which I get using       var mobDevHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;        keeps changing with every single scroll. I expect this to remain constant. Why is this changing ?

Comment: I have found the problem, just trying to find a solution :). scrollPercentage does not hit 101 until you have scrolled about double the length of the screen

Comment: The scroll event is fired a ton of times when you scroll, so you shouldn't be getting the value of `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight` in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I use the module below when working with infinite scrolling. It use a `TableView`, but I would think you can apply it to a ScrollView as well. You need to pass in a `function` that will be called when the `TableView` register that more content should be loaded.

When you have finished loading you must call the `loadingDone`-function in order to enable the `TableView` to initiate another loading sequence.

The value `m_bNoDataFound` ensure that the loading sequence is not initiated, when there is no more data to fill into the list.

You can alter the offsets (currently `0.75` for Android and `0.90` for iOS) if want the loading sequence to be initiated sooner or later during scroll.

```
function TableView( onLoad ) {
    var isAndroid = Ti.Platform.osname === 'android' ? true : false;

    var m_bNoDataFound = false;
    var m_nLastDistance = 0;
    var m_bPulling = false;
    var m_bLoading = false;

    var table = Ti.UI.createTableView( {
        height : Ti.UI.FILL
    } );

    table.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( evt ) {
        //Scroll to load more data
        if( !m_bNoDataFound ) {
            if( isAndroid ) {
                if( !m_bLoading && ( evt.firstVisibleItem + evt.visibleItemCount ) >= ( evt.totalItemCount * 0.75 ) ) {
                    onLoad( true );
                    m_bLoading = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                var nTotal = evt.contentOffset.y + evt.size.height;
                var nEnd = evt.contentSize.height;
                var nDistance = nEnd - nTotal;

                if( nDistance < m_nLastDistance ) {
                    var nNearEnd = nEnd * 0.90;

                    if( !m_bLoading && ( nTotal >= nNearEnd ) ) {
                        onLoad( true );
                        m_bLoading = true;
                    }
                }

                m_nLastDistance = nDistance;
            }
        }
    } );

    function m_fLoadingDone( a_bNoDataFound ) {
        m_bNoDataFound = a_bNoDataFound;

        if( m_bLoading )
            setTimeout( function( ) {
                m_bLoading = false;
            }, 250 );
    }

    return {
        table : table,
        loadingDone : m_fLoadingDone
    };
};

module.exports = TableView;
```

Comment: This doesnot works with scroll view though. But with table view it works well.

Answer (score 1):

When integrating an infinite scroll within a scrollview, there are some important things you have to consider:

**1. scroll event is triggered a lot:** try to throttle your scroll event callback using underscoreJS.

> Throttle creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with. See the underscorejs documentation for more.

**2. Default and system units on Android vs iOS:** The size of a view on Android uses a different display unit than coordinates of a view. This mismatch in units will cause incorrect calculation of your trigger for the infinite scroll. To solve this, you have to get and set the default unit yourself. The solution can be found in this widget (see getDefaultUnit()): https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.color/blob/master/controllers/widget.js

**3. The ti-infini-scroll can help you with this:** this library creates a wrapper around the default Titanium ScrollView. This wrapper contains the calculation of the end of scroll (your trigger for updating/getting new data). When using this library, don't forget to implement bullet number 2.
https://github.com/goodybag/ti-infini-scroll